# Is there any way to choose a specific GPS Provider?

Tags: android, geolocation, gps, geo

I created an app in android which gets the GPS coordinate of the user and shows it in the toast. This is the key line. And of course in the Manifest permission to use ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION being used.

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

When I tested my app on my friends mobile his lat, lng coordinates were
different from mine even though we were hardly one meter apart. I then calculated the distance between his lat,lng and my lat,lng. It came around 330 meters.

Later I thought on possibility that may be his GPS_PROVIDER(satellite) was different and mine was different as his mobile  is not same as mine.

Am I right in thinking along the above line?
If yes, is there any way in android studio where I can specify which GPS Provider to be used? So that next time when I test my app on my friend's mobile our lat,lng coordinates are same.

Answer (score 1):

> Am being right in thinking along the above line?

Not really. There is only one set of GPS satellites. While there are similar systems in various stages of completion (e.g., EU's Galileo), most likely both of your devices are accessing the same system.

> When I tested my app on my friends mobile his lat, lng coordinates were different from mine even though we were hardly one meter apart.

Sure. Different mobile chipsets will have different GPS receivers. Case construction might play an impact, as might slight variations in building construction between the two locations. And so on.

> is there any way in android studio where I can specify which GPS Provider to be used?

No.

Comment: "Case construction might play an impact, as might slight variations in building construction between the two locations". But we were hardly one meter apart!

Comment: @amitoz: So? For example, in an office tower building with steel girders, the entire building is not a single block of solid steel. Not only are there places for you and your friend to sit, but the girders themselves are spaced apart. Being underneath a girder may give different results than not being underneath a girder. This is one of the reasons why cell signal strength varies as you move around a room... and cell towers are much closer to you than are GPS satellites.